# How to run GraphQL request in Pre-Request Script section in postman?

Tags: api, testing, graphql, postman

I want to run a query before the actual request runs and get a value from the pre-request response and set it in a collection variable.
I have a problem running the following as I used to do it while testing REST APIs.

This is what I tried to do

```
const getUserBeforeUpdate = {
  url: pm.environment.get("base-url"),
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
   'content-type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': `Bearer ${pm.environment.get("token")}`},
  body: JSON.stringify({query: '{ user { profile {id} } }'})
};
 
 pm.sendRequest(getUserBeforeUpdate, function(err, response) {
    pm.expect(response.code).to.eql(200);
   
    // set collection variable from the response
 });
```

but I get a console error stating

```
There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  Error: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

What's the right way to chain requests in graphql?

Answer (score 3):

Collection variable are accessible via [collectionVariables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#using-collection-variables-in-scripts). This should work for you:

```
const getUserBeforeUpdate = {
  url: pm.collectionVariables.get("base-url"),
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
   'content-type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': `Bearer ${pm.collectionVariables.get("token")}`},
  body: JSON.stringify({query: '{ user { profile {id} } }'})
};
 
 pm.sendRequest(getUserBeforeUpdate, function(err, response) {
    pm.expect(response.code).to.eql(200);
   
    // set collection variable from the response
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the ability to run you request but would this work?

```js
const getUserBeforeUpdate = {
    url: `${pm.environment.get("base-url")}`,
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${pm.environment.get("token")}`},
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query: 'query { user { profile { id } } }'
    })
};
 
 pm.sendRequest(getUserBeforeUpdate, function(err, response) {
    pm.expect(response.code).to.eql(200);
    // set collection variable from the response
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I'm not sure that I can spot the difference between your answer and my code?

Comment: Did it work? :D I changed that part of your code`JSON.stringify({query: '{ user { profile {id} } }'})`

Comment: No still gives the same error  `Error: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Thank you Danny for taking the time to answer me. I have posted an answer with what worked fine for me but I don't know why :D

Comment: Update to account for the URL reference. I would suggest that you make use of the Postman Console in the app as that would tell you exactly what's sent for the request.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by changing the url value to the actual url directly as a string. I'm not sure why getting the variable from environment didn't work yet.

Comment: Ah, you would probably need to do this - `${pm.environment.get("base-url")}`, I'll update my answer.